# how to get parameters from websocket client request

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am trying the set parameters for authorization `ws://token:@url` how can I get the token params from this request in my server.

Comment: Which module are you using to implement the server? Is it combined with an HTTP server? If so, how/which?

Comment: yes it is, I am also serving the webpage from it, I am using websocket, https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

Comment: Is it really a requirement that the token is passed like that? Would it be an option to pass it as request path (`ws://url/TOKEN`) or query string (`ws://url/?token=TOKEN`)?

Comment: definitely it could, it is not a requirement. I just need something that would work well with my already existing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a look at the `websocket` library, and this is what I came up with:

```
// You need to disable `autoAcceptConnections`...
let wss = new WebSocketServer({ httpServer : server, autoAcceptConnections : false });

// ...so the `request` event is fired, which is needed to access the url parameters
wss.on('request', function(req) {
  // Parse the requested URL:
  let url = require('url').parse(req.httpRequest.url);

  // Assume that the token is passed as path:
  // ws://url/TOKEN
  let token = url.pathname.substring(1); // .substring(1) to strip off the leading `/`

  // Validate token (implementation-dependent):
  if (! isValidToken(token)) return req.reject();

  // Accept the request.
  return req.accept();
});
```

Comment: tnks alot for for your time.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/258

CLIENT:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1234/?id=1&name=foo');
```

SERVER:

```
const url = require('url');

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
  console.log(url.parse(req.url, true).query); // { id: '1', name: 'foo' }
});
```